# Is possible to make temp array updates in real-time in Ionic2?

Tags: javascript, ionic2, real-time

I'm not sure if my question possible but I'm asking if there is any way to make an arraylist that updated in real time

for example, I used "setInterval" to update my temp arraylist such as this:

```
public usersList: FirebaseListObservable < any[] > ;
public chatsList: FirebaseListObservable < any[] > ;
public tempList = [];

public refreshIntervalId;

constructor(...) {
    this.usersList = this.afd.list('/users/');
    this.chatsList = this.afd.list('/chats/');
    this.refreshIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
        this.joinObjects();
    }, 250);
}

joinObjects() {
    let TempListX = [];
    this.chatsList.take(1).subscribe(data1 => {
        this.usersList.take(1).subscribe(data2 => {
            TempListX = data1.slice(0);
            for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
                    if (data1[i].user_id == data2[j].$key) {
                        TempListX[i].fname = data2[j].fname;
                        TempListX[i].lname = data2[j].lname;
                        TempListX[i].uemail = data2[j].email;
                        TempListX[i].uid = data2[j].$key;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (JSON.stringify(TempListX) === JSON.stringify(this.tempList)) {}
            else {
                this.tempList = TempListX.slice();
            }
        })
    })
}
```

So is there any ways better than "setInterval" ?

Answer (score 0):

if the update is based on events then you can use Events (Subscribe and Publish). See documentation.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/